How to Explode the Key value pair of dictionary into multiple rows of dataframe in Python
I have a column in dataframe that contains value in the form of dictionary. Now I want to explode that into multiple rows of the dataframe?
For example:
This is my input dataframe

I want something like this


Please don't use images of data, provide your inputs as text/code.

IMO, the most straightforward is to loop over the dictionaries to explode manually, then merge to the original:
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame([[i, c3, c4] for i, d in zip(df['id'], df['dict_val'])
                             for c3, l in d.items() for c4 in l],
                           columns=['id', 'col3', 'col4']), on='id')

Output:
   id                            dict_val col3 col4
0   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    X    a
1   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    X    b
2   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    Y    c
3   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    Y    d
4   2                   {'Z': ['e', 'f']}    Z    e
5   2                   {'Z': ['e', 'f']}    Z    f


A pure pandas approach most likely would require a double explode:
out = (df.assign(col3=df['dict_val'].apply(list),
                 col4=df['dict_val'].apply(lambda x: x.values()))
         .explode(['col3', 'col4'])
         .explode('col4')
      )

Output:
   id                            dict_val col3 col4
0   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    X    a
0   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    X    b
0   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    Y    c
0   1  {'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']}    Y    d
1   2                   {'Z': ['e', 'f']}    Z    e
1   2                   {'Z': ['e', 'f']}    Z    f

Reproducible input:
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2],
                   'dict_val': [{'X': ['a', 'b'], 'Y': ['c', 'd']},
                                {'Z': ['e', 'f']}]
                  })


What if we are not sure about the number of values in the key-value pair?? In my example I have chosen it is fixed (i.e. 2 values for each key). But what if for each key-value pair , the number of values differ ?

@ZikraNoman that shouldn't matter, any length is fine. The first approach requires however to have a list (iterable) as value (but you could adapt it if needed). The second one should even work with non-iterables.
